# Why doesn't MongoDB's debian jessie package install an init.d script?

Tags: debian, apt, init.d, sysvinit, mongodb

I'm installing MongoDB Community Edition on debian using the [instructions here](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/). It says:

> The mongodb-org-server package provides an initialization script that starts mongod with the /etc/mongod.conf configuration file.

I find that it installs a `systemd` script instead of a `SysVinit` / `init.d` script. Running `dpkg -L` confirms this:

```
$ dpkg -L mongodb-org-server
[...]
/lib/systemd
/lib/systemd/system
/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service
```

But I found that MongoDB does have an `init.d` script, [in their github here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/debian/init.d). Why isn't it installed? Is there some special step I need to follow?

Comment: Well, at least, the systemd service can be enabled: `systemctl enable mongod.service && systemctl start mongod.service`. Just in case that someone found this question, looking for a normal way of daemonizing `mongod` process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [on 2016-02-09 Sam Kleinman of MongoDB decided that it will be this way](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/5495e297c683a92da95cd6a6420dde99ad751df7#diff-b405724ef9b733dd79e0dd9e5858a96eR459).  Debian 7 users get only van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts.  Debian 8 users get only systemd unit files.  No-one gets both.  It was, as you can see, questioned at the time.  But nothing has been done about it since.

This really isn't right for Debian.  In contrast, the packages made by the Debian people are made in a different way, and include both.

Sam Kleinman of MongoDB would appear to be the person to talk to.